# i am trying to upload file in react to firebase and setfileUrl.somehow its giving asyn promise error

Tags: reactjs, file, upload

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNQvJ.png)i am trying to upload file in react to firebase and setfileUrl..somehow its giving asyn promise error...plz help

```
 const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = React.useState(null);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
 
const onFileChange = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const d = uuid();
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(d);
    const fileRef = storageRef.child(file.name);
     fileRef.put(file).on('state_changed', async(snap) => {
      let percentage =  (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100;
     await setProgress(percentage)});
    setFileUrl(await fileRef.getDownloadURL());
  };
```

Comment: can you wrap it in try - catch and console .error the catch, without the error, it's pretty hard to say

Comment: please add await in the start of `fileRef` 
`const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = React.useState(null);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
 
const onFileChange = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const d = uuid();
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(d);
    const fileRef = storageRef.child(file.name);
    await fileRef.put(file).on('state_changed', async(snap) => {
      let percentage =  (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100;
     await setProgress(percentage)});
    setFileUrl(await fileRef.getDownloadURL());
  };`

Comment: i have added the error screenshot plz help.error is still there after adding await in the start of fileRef

Answer (score 0):

try adding this `await` in the start of the `fileRef`

```
const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = React.useState(null);   
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);   
const onFileChange = async (e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];     
  const d = uuid();     
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(d);     
  const fileRef = storageRef.child(file.name);     
  await fileRef.put(file).on('state_changed', 
    async(snap) => {       
      let percentage =  (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100;      
      await setProgress(percentage)});     
      setFileUrl(await fileRef.getDownloadURL());   
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete solution of the problem..
one problem is that.its working on laptop/desktop but image is not uploading using iphone safari browser.any help would be appriciated.

thx

```
function PicUpload({profile,id}) {
  const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = React.useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const types = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg'];

  
  const onFileChange = async (e) => {
    const f = e.target.files[0];
    if (f && types.includes(f.type)) {
      setError('');
    } else {
      setError('Please select an image file (png or jpg)');
    }
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(f.name);
     await   storageRef.put(f).on('state_changed', 
  async(snap) => {       
    let percentage =  (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100;      
     setProgress(percentage)
    console.log(percentage)}).then
    const  setFileUrl = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
     db.collection("profiles").doc(id).update({
     avatar: setFileUrl,
    })
    };
```